# Conflict between HDMI and DVI-D

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi

When I plug in an HDMI display and a DVI-D screen on my graphics card (GeForce GTX 750) neither of these screens are detected.
But all ports are working properly.

It's from my graphics card because it occurs on Linux and Windows

Comment: Which graphics card are you using (Not the generic GTX750, the specific model). Are there any other monitors plugged in?

Comment: It's the Gainward GeForce GTX 750 1GB.

Comment: And yes, I've monitors on all ports

Comment: Hmm, no idea atm. Accorinding to [the specification on their website](http://www.gainward.com/main/edm/GTX750Series/gw_edm_GTX750Series.php) it supports up to three monitors and has three connectors (DVI, HDMI and ancient VGA). I think it should work. Does it display anything during POST ?

Comment: Displays on HDMI and DVI-D not working only 
when they are plugged together. Otherwise, everything works correctly.
And all my monitors are on VGA adaptater

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
Do you think I can buy a VGA splitter and unplug DVI, or it will not work ?

Comment: A VGA splitter will result in the same output on both screens connected to it.